# Draw overlay behind or over navigation bar

Tags: android, overlay, navigationbar

I'm creating an app which should draw fullscreen overlay. Something like lockscreen. The user set some timer and when time is come this overlay should appear.

But overlay doesn't cover system navigation bar. It's a problem when navigation bar is semi-transparent. User can touch system buttons and can see some changeable background behind them. Thus user can see something behind the lock screen. It's a problem.
How could I prevent this situation?

Notice that lock screen overlay is not the activity. User sets timer and can browse his device freely. When the time comes the app draws some view over the screen, like this:

```
View overlayView = new OverlayView(this);

windowManager.addView(overlayView, OverlayView.createLayoutParams(retrieveScreenHeight()));
```

where

```
public OverlayView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflate(context, R.layout.overlay_view, this);
}


static WindowManager.LayoutParams createLayoutParams(int height) {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params =
            new WindowManager.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, height, TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                      FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                    | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
                   , TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    return params;
}


public int retrieveScreenHeight() {
    int result = 0;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    Point outSize = new Point();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(outSize);
    if(outSize.y > outSize.x){
        result = outSize.y;
    }else{
        result = outSize.x;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll want to make the activity that hosts the overlay view as fullscreen if you want to cover the system bar.

Something like below code.

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // remove title
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Then your activity will not show the system bar, and you'll have your view going all the way to the top of the screen.

EDIT : From your last comment, here's how I'd do it :

Step 1 : Create this FullScreenLockActivity :

```
public class FullScreenLockActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // remove title
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      // set to fullScreen
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      //Load your black semi-transparent view
      setContentView(R.layout.lock_screen);
  }

  //Override this to prevent the user to close this activity by pressing the back button
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {}

}
```

Step 2 : Implement your "unlock screen" behavior in the FullScreenLockActivity

Step 3 : To display the lock screen, call

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this, FullScreenLockActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should notice that the overlay view is not an activity. It's just a `View`. I draw it using `windowManager.addView` in any time, regardless of what on the screen. On the screen could be any other app in that time.

Comment: Then the easiest way would be to make that view part of a "dummy activity", fullscreen and with the view as background.
This way, you still see what is behind (since the overlay is semi-transparent), and you benefit from the fullscreen flag.

Comment: You mean when the time is come the app should popup this fullscreen "dummy activity"? And I shouldn't use `windowManager.addView` then? But how could I set this activity as overlay? How can I prevent closing of this activity? It should be Lockscreen which couldn't be closed while the user will not unlock it.

Comment: I added an edit to display this full screen lock activity

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it's not the best way for my problem. Additionally it won't work on a new Android versions and, by the way, `onBackPressed()` is `void`, it can't return `false`. I found an acceptable solution, some tricky workaround with the flags.

Comment: What is the solution you've found? I Really need it a lot. Hope you'll help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @user2775914 Please share your solution